# react-native-calendar arrow style

Tags: react-native, layout, calendar, react-native-calendars

I´m programming in react native and I need to do a calendar. for this, i´m using react-native-calendars library. I need to customize the arrows.

It should be like this:

[image]

But it is like this (the arrow is black because if it were white, it would not be possible to see) :

[image]

The code (style) is this:

```
              style={{
                height: 350,
              }}
              theme={{
                arrowStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#0064D5',
                    color: '#fff',
                    borderRadius: 3,
                    height: 16,
                    width: 16,
                    alignContent: 'top',
                    alignItems: 'top',
                    alignSelf: 'top',
                },
                arrowColor: "#000",
            }}
```

I would like to:

1. Leave the arrows closer to the name of the month;
2. Place the arrow in the center of the blue square;
3. Change the arrow icon. The default arrow icon is this triangle. I want to use the IOS arrow

That is, I want to leave the design the same as the second image.

Can someone help me?

Comment: make things centered by these two followings properties

justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center',

Comment: It solved my problem of the alignment, thank you!! Now all I need to do is change the icon and bring the arrow closer to the middle, I'm still looking for solutions. Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'm still looking for solutions ??

Comment: Yes, I had 3 problems. Thanks to you, I was able to place the arrows in the blue square. But I still need the arrows closer to the month text (November 2023) and change the arrow icon. You can see in the 2nd image there is another icon and the arrows are not at the edge of the screen

Comment: for  arrows closer  add width 40% in main view

Comment: worked!! tahnk you so much!